# how to set default value in select using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have two `dropdown` in my example with reset state (`select bank` `select state`).only first dropdown have data .When I changed first dropdown value then i fetch state data and show in dropdown . if i select `YES BANK` it show me `select state` .Now if I select any state example `Delhi`.then do something.But Now If I change again bank instead of `yes bank` example `Axis bank` state dropdown show `Delhi` why ? it show be reset and show `select state` ?

how to reset second dropdown (when first dropdown is change).here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/7wlwx2volq

Second dropdown always show `select state` with new data of `bank`,when user change `bank name`

```
 onChangeDropdown = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.props.callbackFn(e.target.value);
  };
```

please explain

Comment: May I suggest you rewrite your question and try to be a little more clear with what the problem is and what your trying to do. I realize you want to reset a drop down when the second drop down is clicked, but the whole explanation was hard to follow. Also please show the rest of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is: Instead of using the selected property on options, use [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) means use the value property of select field. Whenever any change happen to bank list, reset the value of state select filed value. Also define the `value=''` with default option.

Like this:

```
<select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.onChangeDropdown}>
    <option value='' disabled>
        {this.props.defaultOption}
    </option>

    {makeDropDown()}
</select>;
```

Pass value from parent component, like this:

```
<DropDown
    value={this.state.bankName}
    data={this.state.bankData}
    defaultOption="select Bank"
    callbackFn={this.callStateService}
/>
<DropDown
    value={this.state.stateName}
    data={this.state.stateData}
    defaultOption="select State"
    callbackFn={this.callDistrictService}
/>
```

Define onChange function for state select field change:

```
callDistrictService = value => {
    this.setState({ stateName: value });
}
```

**[Working Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/98oj2q7ok4)**